# Subtract every column in dataframe with the mean of that column with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mean, centering

I am looking for a way to find means of each column in a python dataframe and subtract that column with the mean of that column.

Suppose I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.5, 2.5], 'b': [0.25, 2.75], 'c': [1.25, 0.75]})
```

I want to find the mean of each column, which would return `(2,1.5,1)` and subtract the values from columns `a`,`b` and `c` respectively.

which would give, `((-0.5,0.5),(-1.25, 1.5), (0.25,-0.25))`

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: mean will return (2,1.5,1) not (2,1.5,2)

Comment: @The6thSense Mybad..calculated wrongly!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could simply use the `mean function of pandas`

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.5, 2.5], 'b': [0.25, 2.75], 'c': [1.25, 0.75]})

print "The data frame"
print df
print "The mean value"
print df.mean()
print "The value after subraction of mean"
print df -df.mean()
```

**Output:**

```
The data frame

    a     b     c
0  1.5  0.25  1.25
1  2.5  2.75  0.75

The mean value

a    2.0
b    1.5
c    1.0
dtype: float64

The value after subraction of mean

    a     b     c
0 -0.5 -1.25  0.25
1  0.5  1.25 -0.25
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
>>> df
     a     b     c
0  1.5  0.25  1.25
1  2.5  2.75  0.75
>>> df.columns
Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')
>>> for x in df.columns:
...     df[x] = df[x] - df[x].mean()
... 
>>> df
     a     b     c
0 -0.5 -1.25  0.25
1  0.5  1.25 -0.25
```

Pythonic way:

```
>>> df - df.mean()
     a     b     c
0 -0.5 -1.25  0.25
1  0.5  1.25 -0.25
```

Comment: In your `for loop` you are doing the same thing that `df - df.mean()` does but `df - df.mean()` would be faster and your method has more flexibility .

Comment: The DataFrame.apply() function can replace the loop.